# Formatting a comment

Tags: support, comments, formatting

Is it possible to format a comment, as in, include blockqoute like properties?
I've noticed that the help mentions that 'code' can be used for code, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Either that, or I made an error in understanding it. Any which way, is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope. Comments are limited to:

```
**bold**
*italics*
`code`
[link text](http://example.com)
```

There are also a few shortcuts for mentioning things like edit links, etc. See [the full help on comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for a better understanding.

Comment: I've tried to use the 'code' option, but I don't see a change really. Is that where I'm going wrong? if i put something within quotation marks when the comment is posted, will it be seen that way, with the quotation marks?

Comment: They're not quotations, they're backticks. On a English keyboard, the button to the left of `1` on the number row should do it.

Comment: Damn, my bad, i've been seeing them wrong all this while, thanks a lot!

Comment: So *that's* how you insert a line break...   
I've been wondering how to do that for ages. Very useful link indeed.
Edit: Oh wait, that was odd. The rest of the page seems unrelated to comments. Ah well. I'm guessing then that there isn't a way of doing it? The only hope left would be &nbsp; but somehow I doubt that'd do it either.

Comment: And, predictably, it didn't. Oh well.

Comment: @JezW No, as far as I know there aren't any methods to force a newline in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was mistaking single quotes for backticks. The backtick char is the key located to the left of the 1 on your keyboard, it also has the tilde character on it.

` and ~

not the single quote char '