# In comments, how to write blocs of commands?

Tags: support, comments

In questions, I was used to write the < pre > without spaces before a bloc and < /pre > without spaces after it. Maybe it is the old way. Now, I have tried it in a comment and it does not work. I mean such a bloc as is in the third comment at my question [how to check a filesystem in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953728/how-to-check-a-filesystem-in-ubuntu-16-04). There, the bloc contains 'sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb{something}'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments have a much more limited set of [formatting commands](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7014/5) than questions and answers. There is, however, an option for demarcating code in a comment:

```
`code goes here`
```

Note that the ` character is a backtick and not an apostrophe. It can usually be typed by pressing the button immediately to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key on a US keyboard.

Comment: I hope the bloc mentioned in the question is `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb{something}`

Comment: Now I see that the way may be used also in questions , instead of my `<pre>`.